# Is there a way to compare values in two excel workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello all and a good year to you!

My goal here is to open a workbook say workbook A, I want to copy the entire workbook to workbook B, however I want to compare two columns that contain two different numbers. So, if workbook A has those numbers and workbook B has those numbers, copy that entire row from workbook A to workbook B, overwriting it. There is always new data produced by workbook B and I want to keep that while it overwrites current rows.

Here is my code so far, it just opens up a dialog box to select which file to compare to, and copies the entire sheet from workbook A to workbook B, but I am struggling on this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fullpath As String

Sub copyDATA()
 
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        .Show
        
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    
    If InStr(fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

Worksheets("Daily").Range("A1:Q2000").Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
fullpath
    
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Daily").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

I have a previous date workbook that has all the formatting, comments, and what not. The new workbook generates without formatting or anything, but has updated data in the cells. What I need to do is copy or merge the previous workbook into the new generated workbook, which carries everything over including formatting but leaves the new data in the new workbook alone.

Comment: I suggest you research Range.AdvancedFilter.

Comment: Do you want to add rows into B from A that don't match B ? Are the rows in A and B in the same order ?

Comment: NicholasHunter I will do that! @CDP1802 No I don't want to add any rows I just want to overwrite them with A to B, and yes A and B will match except for new data pulled to B. I just have to make sure that data exists in both rows of A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the columns you want to compare are "B" and "C" in both workbooks

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyDATA()
   
    Const SHT_NAME = "Daily"
    Const COL_KEY1 = "B"
    Const COL_KEY2 = "C"

    Dim wbA As Workbook, wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wbB As Workbook, wsB As Worksheet, row As Range
    Dim iLastrowA As Long, iLastrowB As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String, count(2) As Long

    ' choose workbook A
    Dim fullpath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
        FileName = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    
    ' check is xls
    If InStr(FileName, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    ' workbook B is this workbook
    Set wbB = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsB = wbB.Sheets(SHT_NAME)

    ' build dict of existing key numbers
    Dim dict As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    iLastrowB = wsB.Cells(Rows.count, COL_KEY1).End(xlUp).row
    For iRow = 1 To iLastrowB
        key = Trim(wsB.Cells(iRow, COL_KEY1)) & _
              Trim(wsB.Cells(iRow, COL_KEY2))
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            MsgBox "Dupicate key " & key & " at row " & iRow, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Left(key, 7) Like "#######" Then ' 7 digit number
            dict(key) = iRow
        End If
    Next

    ' source data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(FileName, True, True)
    Set wsA = wbA.Sheets(1)
    iLastrowA = wsA.Cells(Rows.count, COL_KEY1).End(xlUp).row
    For iRow = 1 To iLastrowA
        key = Trim(wsA.Cells(iRow, COL_KEY1)) & _
              Trim(wsA.Cells(iRow, COL_KEY2))
        Set row = wsA.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(1, 17) 'A to Q
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            ' update values only
            row.Copy
            wsB.Cells(dict(key), 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            count(1) = count(1) + 1
            'highlight updated row - comment out when working
            wsB.Cells(dict(key), 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        
        ElseIf Left(key, 7) Like "#######" Then ' valid 7 digit numbers
            ' add if needed later
            'iLastrowB = iLastrowB + 1
            'row.Copy
            'wsB.Cells(iLastrowB, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            'count(2) = count(2) + 1
            'wsB.Cells(iLastrowB, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'g
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox count(1) & " rows updated " & count(2) & " added from " & wbA.Name, vbInformation
    wbA.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's getting me to where I need it to go; however the error handler in the code, I am getting a duplicate key error, can we resolve this? I do have a lot of duplicates and need those to be over written.

Comment: @calibur Are there duplicates in workbook A ?

Comment: Yes multiple, this is an example of two rows within A and B, act as if A is a day old file and B as a new file with updated data.                                                                                `TEST INC 5166355 10 BC-FL-MOD-A 72HS61.5 F90 RH RI 1 1 3/24/2021 1/14/2021 3/24/2021  8,890.00  YBAT Scheduled Not yet processed test.user US30
TESTS INC 5166355 20 BC-FL-MOD-A 72HS61.5 F90 LH LI 1 1 3/24/2021 1/14/2021 3/24/2021  8,890.00  YBAT Scheduled Not yet processed test.user US30`
'

Comment: @calibur Are the records uniquely identified by a combination of columns like `5166355 20` and `5166355 10` ? Are those in col A and B.

Comment: Yes! But I believe those numbers are in column B and C.

Comment: I tried running and got an error COL_KEY not defined so I tried to define it and it didn't work, says 0 copied 0 rows added.

Comment: Okay I updated, and it's not working. It's just saying 0 copied.. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated with screenshots, you can view them at the links provided.

Comment: Okay, do I need to change anything within the code or?

Comment: @calibur yes I have corrected source data key to use wsA for both key columns. It looks like you only want to copy values not formats as well.